# Expo FileSystem.uploadAsync with multiple files

Tags: react-native, expo, blob, multipartform-data

I got new requirements to support the upload of multiple files in a single request, in my Expo React Native app. The use case is submitting a case with data fields and attached files (so a multipart form request). I used to support a single file using Expo's: `FileSystem.uploadAsync`, and the code looks like this:

```
   const options = {
       mimeType: claimData.fileAttachment.mimeType,
       uploadType: FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
       fieldName: "file",
       headers: {
          // Auth token and other headers
       },
       parameters: {
         // The data fields I mentioned
       },
     };

    return await uploadAsync(apiUrl, singleFileUrl, options);
```

After carefully reading the [Expo docs of the FileSystem API](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemuploadasyncurl-fileuri-options)
I haven't found any suggestion on how to handle multiple files, has anyone faced this before? How could I support it without doing a radical change in backend code.

Answer (score -1):

Build a list of files to be uploaded then upload them as batch.

```js
async function uplaodFile({ fileName, fileUrl }) {
  const options = {
    mimeType: claimData.fileAttachment.mimeType,
    uploadType: FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
    fieldName: fileNmae,
    headers: {
      // Auth token and other headers
    },
    parameters: {
      // Extra fields
    },
  };

  return await uploadAsync(apiUrl, fileUrl, options);
}

async function uploadFiles() {
  const files = [
    {
      fileName: "File-01",
      fileUrl: "file://path/to/file1",
    },
    {
      fileName: "File-02",
      fileUrl: "file://path/to/file2",
    },
    {
      fileName: "File-03",
      fileUrl: "file://path/to/file3",
    },
  ];

  try {
    const uploadPromises = files.map(
      async (file) => await uploadFile({ ...file }),
    );

    const uploadResponses = await Promise.all(uploadPromises);
    //uploadResponses will contains list of file upload response (resolves & rejects)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with more details. It needs to be a single request, isn't this multiple requests?

Comment: Promise.all will execute multiple file upload requests in parallel.

Comment: Alternative not work with standard Expo Go - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs#file-upload-android-and-ios-only